# Hey guys, How can I add more sheets to search on my current script?

Tags: google-apps-script

my current [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jm0V334dACOYhB3_p4JmlhxE9ppVTqAWxsboDKDSe3c/edit#gid=1991064860) checks 'Dec 2019' sheet and if the criteria is met. He will then make a copy of the row to sheet2.

Right now, I wanted the search not just on 'Dec 2019' but also in other monthly sheet. I have different worksheet for each month.

Need help on making my script correct.

```
function onEdit(event) {
 // assumes source data in sheet named main
 // target sheet of move to named Completed
 // getColumn with drop-downs is currently set to column 3 or C
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
 var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

 if(s.getName() == "Dec 2019" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "No") {
   var row = r.getRow();
   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
   var values = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).getValues()[0];
   var resultRow = [values[0], values[1], values[2]];
   targetSheet.appendRow(resultRow);
 } 
}
```

Comment: Nvm found a workaround.

I just removed the value on s.getName()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code contains

`if(s.getName() == "Dec 2019" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "No") {`

This means that your request will carried out if the name of the edited sheet is "Dec 2019" and the edited column "7" and the value "No"

**If you want to apply the same condition (edited column "7" and the value "No") also to other sheets - either you need to implement an `or` [operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) "||",
e.g.**

`if((s.getName() == "Dec 2019" || s.getName() == "Nov 2019") && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "No") {`

or, if you want to perform the request for all sheets in your spreadsheet - just remove the frist condition completely:

`if(r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "No") {`